# How to create triggers which ensure the column value range and applies to insert and updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have create a triggers but its not working as I want. For example, I want to make sure that the order_limits filed should be between 1-10 and it should applied with insert and updates. But I cannot able to figure out how to make it work with updates and insert. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

```
CREATE TRIGGER trRestrictRange
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN 
 ALTER TABLE Order
ADD CONSTRAINT const_range CHECK (order_limits >=1 AND order_limits <= 10 );
END
```

Comment: You appear to be writing a DDL trigger but you talk about DML operations. Why, however, not just use a Constraint? Why do you *need* a Trigger?

Comment: Seems to me like you don't need to use a trigger for this at all. DDL statements such as alter table should be design time operations (with a few exceptions). Seems to me like simply running the alter table statement should be enough.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for your comment. There is another way to where we ensure the value of a column should be between 1 to 10 in DML triggers? I will appreciate you help.

Comment: @Larnu I need to use triggers to apply range rule on column orders_limit to stay between 1 to 10 whenever we make insert or updates.

Comment: Answering "Why do you *need* to do this?" by telling me *"I need to do this"*, doesn't tell me *why* you need to do it. *Why* do you **need** to use a `TRIGGER`? Why *can't* you use a `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: @Larnu Its a requirement. that why I need to use trigger for this purpose. I am just stuck on this point and lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "must" use a trigger (there is no *good* reason why you "must") then you need to use a DML trigger, not a DDL trigger, and check the data in the `inserted` pseudo table. Then, if the data exists in the table, `THROW` an error:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Chktrg_OrderRange ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted i
               WHERE order_limits < 1 
                  OR order_limits > 10)
        THROW 98765, N'The Trigger check Chktrg_OrderRange on the table ''dbo.YourTable'' failed. The column ''order_limits'' must be more than or equal to one and less than or equal to 10.', 16;
END;
```

Of course, as I stated, there is no *good* reason to do this, and you should, instead, be using a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_OrderRange
CHECK (order_limits >= 1 AND order_limits <= 10);
```

Comment: Just a question, can you explain me about why you use Select and inserted i. Thanks

Comment: How else would I see what data is in the `inserted` table, if not a `SELECT`, @Yasir ?