# How to check if the id of one table is exists in another table using triggers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have created this trigger but when I am trying to insert or update the record this code is not working properly.For example, when I am trying to insert record into order table with customer id that does not exist in the customer table, then it should show a message 'Yes' instead of 'No'. Just need you help to check where I am wrong. Thanks

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_checkKey 
ON ORDER
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM inserted
               JOIN
                   (SELECT ID FROM Order
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ID FROM Customer) Order_Customer ON Order_Customer.ID = inserted.ID)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Yes';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO'
    END

    -- THROW 98765, N'The Trigger check Chktrg_OrderRange on the table ''dbo.YourTable'' failed. The column ''order_limits'' must be more than or equal to one and less than or equal to 10.', 16;
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is **`AFTER`** the `INSERT`, so the row you just inserted is already in the table.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to achieve here? This has a smell of abuse of triggers again, if I am honest.

Comment: @Larnu So need to use BEFORE here?

Comment: I don't think you want a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Also, in SQL Server, there is no `BEFORE` trigger, only `INSTEAD OF`, and `AFTER`, and I *doubt* an `INSTEAD OF` is a good idea here.

Comment: I want it as I mentioned in my last question, Its an requirement for me to do this task from my tech lead. If I get tip here then it would be lot easier for me to  worked on more in future.

Comment: Then explain what you *actually* need to do here. Though, personally, I would suggest talking to your "tech lead", they are giving you non-sensical requirements. I would start by asking them "What do you have against `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`s, and why can't I use them?"

Comment: this trigger make sure that the Customer ID in the Order table is one of the customer if from the customer table. If not then print message.

Comment: So why are you not using a Foreign key? And why are you checking if the value is in the `Order` table, if it should be in the `Customer` table. This is, once again, just abuse of `TRIGGER`s; just stop doing this and use `CONSTRAINT`s.

Comment: There is any possibility we can do it with trigger, just asking..if yes can you please give me clue. Thanks

Comment: Fool me once, shame of me, fool me twice... I gave the benefit of the doubt for the first (ab)use of a `TRIGGER` in your prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74343370), but I cannot in good faith give a solution that is so fundamentally wrong a second time.

Comment: instead of works perfectly. But I checked your solution which is suitable in this case.Thanks

Comment: Did you handle the `INSERT` in your `INSTEAD OF` `TRIGGER`? If not, it's not working "perfectly".

Comment: I did handle the Insert with INSTEAD OF and its working perfectly.

Comment: Just remember then, that if you ever change the definition of your table to add (or remove) columns, you need to also `ALTER` your `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that this is another example of trying to get a square peg through a circular hole. Like in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74343370/2029983), this is not what a `TRIGGER` is for; `CONSTRAINT`s are what you need to be using.

You should be using a `FOREIGN KEY` `CONSTRAINT` here. Stop abusing `TRIGGER`s; they aren't to be used for which they can be solved with in-built features:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Order] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OtherTable_YourTable_ID --ORDER is a reserved keyword, don't use it for object names
FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES dbo.Customer (ID); --If the Customer is the ID, what is the ID for the Order called?
```